# ASP.NET Core MVC dropdown list on _layout page to a Session variable

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been looking for a good example of this but all i find is regular ASP.NET MVC.  Although i would like to populate the drop down list from a database, and i already have a controller that pulls that for another page.  For now, all i want is a simple 5 selection drop down list that i can add manually on the layout page with the Nav Bar.  How would i make that selection dynamically a session and will remain the same on every page until another is selected?

reason: This selection is the location of offices and each one has different data specific for that location, so i will use that Session variable in all controllers/Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter that this is Core or regular MVC. You would let the framework store a value for the current user open selection from your drop down. You can read more about session state in Core at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state.